# The inverse square law of sound through solids?

Tags: waves, acoustics, power, density, vibrations

We all know about the [inverse square law of sound](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/acoustic/invsqs.html). In short the power of the wave will get evenly spread on an ever increasing spherical expansion and this will dissipate the power of the wave at a rate of inverse squared to the distance travelled.

[image]

But what about sound waves travelling through a solid like a rectangular table? Is there such a law that relates the power of a signal to the distance travelled? Even a approximation of the relationship would help; is this an inverse square relations as well?
[image]

Comment: It's just inverse first power because the plate is 2-dimensional, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say two dimensional, rather a three dimensional cylinder with a set height and increasing radius. But if we make the math incredibly easy and assume the same laws are applied here.

Comment: Using that simplification we could have I = P / (2 π r h)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127282/51994

Comment: In your question you only analyze power dissipated in the radial direction. There are also forces or stresses tangentially due to Poisson's ratio, and there are also normal stress in the tangential direction due to tangential strain. Don't you think you should include those in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is that your table, or whatever object it is, will act as a [waveguide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide). That's because the sound waves will (partially) reflect of the wood/air surface then travel back into the table and interfere with other waves. The result is going to be hideously complicated to calculate.

As Luboš says in a comment, if the thickness of the table is much less than the wavelength of the sound then the system effectively becomes two dimensional. If we can ignore energy loss from the flat surfaces then when you bang the middle of the table then the energy will spread out in rings and fall off as $\tfrac{1}{r}$ rather than $\tfrac{1}{r^2}$. But even in this simple case as soon as the sound waves hit the edges of the table they will reflect back and start interfering with other waves and you can get all sorts of [complicated patterns](http://www.mathphysics.com/pde/ch10nb.html).

So I'm afraid that in general for a finite sized object the sound intensity isn't going to decrease in any simple way.

Comment: Dear John, I think that the plate is effectively 2-dimensional even if the thickness is (much) more than the wavelength. It is 2-dimensional as soon as the wave spreads to the whole thickness. The energy density is then pretty much independent of the (compact) vertical direction of the plate, at least in average, and energy conservation implies that the energy will decrease as $1/r$ even if there are some fun short-term patterns.